# Code-Blocks Mistake Highlighting

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Is there a Plugin that goes through your CB C++ Code and highlights your mistakes?
Similar to Eclipse or Visual Studio?
SO that you can see if you made a mistake before compiling?

Or if it doesn't, is there a C++ Linux IDE that can do that?

Comment: Eclipse itself has a [C/C++ IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/c.php).

Comment: I has absolutely no idea about that, either, but it took me five seconds of Google search to find it, including the time to type the search string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick answer, just to add a little more knowledge to this topic:
You must definitely check out [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/). Netbeans 6.7 has the following features:

C/C++ Projects and Templates: Supports syntax highlighting, automatic code completion, automatic indentation.
It has a C/C++ Debugger
Supports Compiler Configurations, Configuration Manager and Makefile Support (with a Wizard).
It has a Classes Window, a Usages Window and a File Navigation Window (or panel).
[A Macro expansion view](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyMilestone2NB67#section-NewAndNoteworthyMilestone2NB67-MacroExpansionView), and also tooltips.
Support for QT development.
I think it's a perfect (and far better) Visual Studio substitution, and a very good tool to learn C/C++.

Good Luck!

EDIT:
I also have a few other favorites, which in my opinion are good substitutes for what you are looking for.

-KDevelop4 
-CodeBlocks 8.02

Comment: didn't know that you could make C++ with NB, ill have a look at it thanks. I hope its compatible with gcc ogre bullet and stuff like that.